# Why would it take a delay x-milliseconds long for a variable change to take effect?

Tags: javascript

I'm running into an interesting issue with a ticker that controls a parachute's movement. Whenever the acceleration direction is changed, it takes exactly 60 milliseconds before it takes effect which results in some odd behavior, such as the parachute hitting the game wall and 'grinding' before it swaps direction.

When it hits the wall, in this test case it should immediately change directions. It would seem to be the offset loop causing this, however I've run the base code without the loop and it still acts in the same manner.

The base engine is Phaser 3, with the tick() running directly inside it's Update() loop.

I have tested this directly with both setInterval, and requestAnimationFrame - they produce the same odd delay.

```
tick(time)
{
    if (this.last == 0)
    {
        this.last = time;
    }

    let offSet = Math.min(time - this.last, 5000);

    let dragMod = (1 - this.drag);

    for(let i = 0; i < offSet; i++);
    {
        if (!this.isGrounded)
        {
            if (this.AccelDirection == -1)
            {
                this.XSpeed += -this.windPower;
            }

            if (this.AccelDirection == 0)
            {
                this.XSpeed = 0;
            }                 

            if (this.AccelDirection == 1)
            {
                this.XSpeed += this.windPower;
            } 

            this.YSpeed += this.gravity;
            this.X += this.XSpeed;
            this.Y += this.YSpeed;

            this.YSpeed *= dragMod;
            this.XSpeed *= dragMod;

            if (this.X >= 868)
            {
                this.X = 868; // Right //
                if (this.isMe)
                {
                    this.AccelDirection = -this.AccelDirection;
                    //this.scene.bounce();
                }

            }

            if (this.X <= 32)
            {
                this.X = 32; // Left //
                if (this.isMe)
                {
                    this.AccelDirection = -this.AccelDirection;
                    //this.scene.bounce();
                }
            } 

        } else {
            this.YSpeed = 0;
            this.XSpeed = 0;
        }

        if (this.Y > 868)
        {
            this.isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    this.x = this.X;
    this.y = this.Y;
    this.last = time;
}
```

I've watched the loop with a console.log, and it recognizes it the second that it hits the condition, often counting up to 59 milliseconds before it changes.

Comment: How do you run the `tick` function? Via `requestAnimationFrame`? With `setInterval`?

Comment: A bit aside, you could reduce and simplify the code by combining `AccelDirection` to speed calculations, that would let you leave multiple chekings out of the code.

Comment: The base engine is Phaser 3, and the tick is running inside it's Update() loop

Comment: Okay, I've got a partial answer. It's the Frame Rate causing this behavior. However, I need to figure out where to add Frame Rate Independence.

Comment: Why do you need that loop to begin with? Looks to me like it doesn't do anything useful except changing properties for N number of times (depending on the value of `offSet`, which might be really high because it calculates the difference in time based on elapsed time). You can get rid of it entirely by multiplying the `offSet` value with whatever value you want to update. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves it, but you can get rid of the loop entirely:

```js
tick(time)
{
    if (!this.last) {
      // cannot compute offset without a "last" property 
      this.last = time;
      return;
    }

    let offSet = Math.min(time - this.last, 5000);
    let dragMod = (1 - this.drag);

    let ySpeed = this.gravity;
    let xSpeed = this.AccelDirection < 0 ? -this.windPower :
                 this.AccelDireciton < 1 ? 0 :
                 /* otherwise */           this.windPower;

    this.isGrounded = this.Y > 868;
    if (!this.isGrounded) {
      this.XSpeed += xSpeed * offSet;
      this.YSpeed += ySpeed * offSet;
      this.X += this.XSpeed;
      this.Y += this.YSpeed;
      this.XSpeed *= dragMod;
      this.YSpeed *= dragMod;

      if (this.isMe) {
        if (this.X >= 868 || this.X <= 32) {
          this.X = this.X >= 868 ? 868 : 32;
          this.AccelDirection *= -1;
          // this.scene.bounce();
        }
      }
    } else {
      this.XSpeed = this.YSpeed = 0;
    }

    this.x = this.X;
    this.y = this.Y;
    this.last = time;
}
```

Comment: This is actually net code, designed to keep it in sync with server commands - that's what the loop is for, the time is based on the last server time. I'll test it both ways down the line, but right now the main issue is figuring out frame rate independence.

Comment: On a whim I decided to try testing things this way, and the sprite won't even move with this.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Turned out to be

```
let dragMod = (1 - this.drag);
```

This whole time. Not the net loop, time, etc. Adding framerate independence helped, but I had to alter the drag timing. That was causing the unusual delay.